# Issue with paint time using bootstrap carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions, carousel, repaint, reflow

So I'm using Bootstrap Carousel to create a simple slider, but the issue is that when the transitions are fired for the first time the paint time takes a lot for each slide, but after that they seem to be just fine, my guess is that the first transitions are causing a reflow and this is why it happens, not sure though.

[This is what I see in Chrome Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZMpL.png)

Also this is the link to the carousel: http://dev.around25.net/inzimo/#/weddings

Any suggestion to fix this would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I just figured that using the `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` hack on the carousel works ok on Chrome. Any other suggestions are still welcomed though.